# I need help writing this batch script

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, batch-file, switch-statement

I want to have this script execute another script if a file name starts with one thing, another if it starts with another thing, and to continue on through the rest of the code if it starts with anything else. I want it to iterate through all the files in a folder and check against this. I have been working on it for a while and am looking for a fresh set of eyes since apparently I can't seem to get it working properly. Any help would be appreciated!

```
 :========================================================================================
:: purpose: 1. copy file(s) from the export dir (SOURCE_DIR) (ARCHIVE_DIR)
::          2. copy file(s) from the export dir (SOURCE_DIR) (TARGET_DIR)
::          3. once file(s) are processed delete them from the export dir (SOURCE_DIR)
::=======================================================================================
::      
@echo off
setlocal
:: Display the command line on the window's Title Bar
title %0 %1
set LOG_FILE="here.txt"
set SOURCE_DIR=here\there
set TARGET_DIR=here\nowHere
set ARCHIVE_DIR=here\oldStuffnThings
set FILE=FileStartingWithBlahBlergOrOther.docx


echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- >> %LOG_FILE%
echo %DATE% %TIME% Starting file move >> %LOG_FILE%


if not exist "%SOURCE_DIR%%FILE%" (
  echo %DATE% %TIME% "%SOURCE_DIR%%FILE%" not found >> %LOG_FILE%
  echo %DATE% %TIME% no files to move so stopping >> %LOG_FILE%
  exit
)


FOR /R %completepath% %%G IN (FileStartingWithBLAH*) DO (
  call C:\otherScript1
)

FOR /R %completepath% %%G IN (FileStartingWithBLERG*) DO (
  call C:\otherScript2
)





:: one at a time copy files to archive, copy to dir, then delete from the export dir
FOR /R %SOURCE_DIR% %%G IN (%FILE%) DO (
echo %DATE% %TIME% %%G was found for processing >> %LOG_FILE%
XCOPY %%G "%ARCHIVE_DIR%"/Y 
echo %DATE% %TIME% %%G was archived status %ERRORLEVEL% >> %LOG_FILE% 
XCOPY %%G "%TARGET_DIR%"/Y 
echo %DATE% %TIME% %%G was copied to  dir status %ERRORLEVEL% >> %LOG_FILE%
del %%G
echo %DATE% %TIME% %%G was deleted from the export dir status %ERRORLEVEL% >> %LOG_FILE%
)

rem set err_code=%errorlevel%
rem if %err_code% NEQ 0 (
rem    echo %DATE% %TIME% **ERROR moving files %err_code% >> %LOG_FILE%
rem    exit     
rem )
rem echo %DATE% %TIME% File(s) moved successfully >> %LOG_FILE%

rem echo %DATE% %TIME% Process Complete >> %LOG_FILE%
```

Comment: You are missing problem in the post... only what you are trying to do... Consider removing `echo off` and see if you can make more sence of your script output... then add what issues you have with the script to your post.

Comment: Please edit your question and make the title something meaningful. "I need help" isn't useful to future users trying to find a solution to a problem; it has absolutely no meaning as a search result. It also tells us nothing about the issue you're having or what your problem might be. Also, saying "It's not working" doesn't help if you don't tell us what "not working" means. We can't see your screen or read your mind from where we are, and so you need to give us the information we need to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that you have to put a backslash after `SOURCE_DIR=here\there` or it will look for `here\thereFileStartingWithBlahBlergOrOther.docx`

Comment: It is stopping after executing one of the scripts being called within it. Also, it seems to ignore the 2 first calls and just executes the bottom part.

Comment: What do you see when you remove echo off, is `%completepath%` defined? Are there any FileStartingWithBLAH*? There also could be a problem in the script if it stops at the script.